# jQuery DataTables Pagination showing vertically

Tags: asp.net, datatables

Hello I am trying to display data using jQuery DataTables and my pagination is displaying vertically. Here is the code

```
<head>
        <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#dtUsers').DataTable({
                    "ajax": "../api/GetActiveMembers/GetData",
                    "columns": [
                        //{ "data": "UserId" },
                        { "data": "FirstName" },
                        { "data": "LastName" },
                        { "data": "Email" },
                        { "data": "UserRole" },
                        { "data": "Organization" },
                        { "data": "LastLoginDate" },
                        { "data": "ButtonData" }
                    ]
                });
            });
        </script>

        <title>View Active Users</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="divTable" runat="server" visible="true">
            <div class="myDiv">
                <h1 class="mb-1">Active Users</h1>
            </div>
            <table id="dtUsers" class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <%--<th>User ID</th>--%>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Role</th>
                        <th>Organization</th>
                        <th>Last Login</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
```

I am also attaching an image of how it is looking right now
[image]

Can someone please tell me how I can fix this? I cannot find anything like this online.

Edit: This is how it should look like
[image]

THanks

Comment: The code you posted seems unrelated to the issue. Maybe there's something else in your page/HTML/CSS conflicting with the default DataTables behaviour

Answer (score 1):

This did the trick. Thank you all

```
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button {
    display: inline; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick Solution (If I understood correctly)

```html
<style>
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button
{
    width: 100% !important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: No luck. I added an image of how it's supposed to look like

Comment: You said in the title that you want to display it vertically. Then there is no datatable error in your code. There is a different error. When I tried your example codes, the result is as you want.

Comment: No the pagination is displaying vertically when it should be horizontal. I updated my original question to include both images.

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be easier to use a listview, or gridview? They both support paging, and are quite easy.

Say this markup:

```
    <div style="width:50%;padding:20px">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
            DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="5">                
            <PagerStyle CssClass="GridPager" />
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
```

And then our code:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadGrid
    End If
End Sub


Sub LoadGrid()

    Dim strSQL As String =
        "SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, HotelName, City, Description, Active 
         FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName"

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Using cmdSQL As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
            cmdSQL.Connection.Open()
            Dim rstTable As New DataTable
            rstTable.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
            GridView1.DataSource = rstTable
            GridView1.DataBind()
        End Using
    End Using


End Sub

Protected Sub GridView1_PageIndexChanging(sender As Object, e As GridViewPageEventArgs) Handles GridView1.PageIndexChanging

    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
    LoadGrid()

End Sub
```

And we get this:

[image]

Now, I did grab a css format for the pager - can't remember where, but I have this:

But, this css was used for the pager:

```
<style type="text/css">
.GridPager a, .GridPager span
{
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.GridPager a
{
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    color: #969696;
    border: 1px solid #969696;
}
.GridPager span
{
    background-color: #A1DCF2;
    color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #3AC0F2;
}
</style>
```